# SharePoint 2016 psconfig error related to ManageUserProfileServiceApplicationTenantSimplifies.xml

Tags: sharepoint

I have installed SharePoint 2016 and get this  error while running configuration wizard - could not find ManageUserProfileServiceApplicationTenantSimplifies.xml.
Any ideas ?

I came across this link and it says this is a bug but can be ignored - http://code2care.org/2015/sharepoint-2016-error-could-not-find-file-manageuserprofileserviceapplicationtenantsimplified.xml.

Though I could complete the configuration, will this be an issue ?

Comment: Is you user profile service application running?

Comment: yes UPS is running and working fine

Comment: no responses, so I consider there is not much information available on this error yet. Seems will need to wait till RTM is out.